# Custom sequence generation in multithreaded & cluster environment

Tags: java, oracle, sequence

I am looking for the options to solve the custom sequence generation problem. Let me describe my problem by giving an example:

Let say, there are two tables company and employee table,

```
Table: Company
-----------------------------------------------
CompanyId  | CompanyName | LatestSequenceValue
-----------------------------------------------
    c1     |     XYZ     |   100 
    c2     |     ABC     |   150
-----------------------------------------------
Table: Employee
----------------------------------------------------------
EmployeeId | EmployeeName  | CompanyId | EmployeeSurveyNo
----------------------------------------------------------
    e1     |     NVERMA     |    c1    |   101 
    e1     |     DAVID      |    c1    |   102
    e2     |     VGUPTA     |    c2    |   151
    e2     |     MAC        |    c2    |   152
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Whenever, employee joins the company, he is asked to complete the company specific survey and after completion of the survey, '**Survey No**' is generated based on **LatestSequenceValue** from company table.

To generate the survey no below steps are performed:

1. Read the current sequence value specific to a company from company table (**LatestSequenceValue**)
2. Increment the sequence count by 1
3. Use this incremented value to log into employee table as '**EmployeeSurveyNo**'
4. Also, update the incremented value in company table (**LatestSequenceValue**) so next survey should get proper sequence.

Before converting above approach into the program/logic, below points should be kept in mind:

1. Application can be deployed in cluster environment
2. Application supports Multi threading
3. Last but not least, application supposed to do 50K surveys in one hour.

What should be the proper approach to solve this custom sequence generation problem?

Optimistic locking at database level can be good idea. But this approach may somehow degrade the performance.

Is there any thing like In-Memory sequence generation that can handle above problem and  improve the performance?

Ideas/Suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: I would have it access thee same server every time. 16 increments a second should be trivial.

Comment: You are going to have one database still.. isnt it ?

Comment: @Peter: I didn't catch your point. Could you please provide detail?

Comment: If you update the same database and let it replicate around the cluster, you won't run into consistency issues such as performance.  One database should be able to handle 100s if not 1000s of updates per second.

Comment: @Maheswaran: Yes, I will be using database. But, I would like to avoid database operations like select (fetching current sequence value) and update (update sequence with incremented sequence) just to handle sequence generation specific to the company.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: Database can handle sequence updates even I have clustered environment. Only concern is about Performance.

Comment: @NarendraVerma I have a NoSQL database called Java-Chronicle and it can handle 5-40 *million* inserts per second, replicated over TCP.  You shouldn't need to worry about 16 per second even on a mobile phone let alone a server.

Comment: What I am thinking is, If I go with database optimistic locking and 100 threads pick the sequence number say '198' and any of the thread  s increment it by 1 and saves incremented sequence '199' into company table. Now for other 99 threads sequence number '198' is no more valid as it is updated by other thread with value '199'. Now the failure case is almost 99%. In this case for other 99 thread I have to select the current sequence and perform the same action. Wouldn't it be performance hit? (I am using Oracle Database which is RDBMS)

Comment: @NarendraVerma SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL is the only call to the DB. And oracle would automatically increment it as per your SEQUENCE definition, disregarding how many threads access it parallely.. It is synchronized! It should be simple and safe approach. Performance wise, if you use connection pools and hence by reusing connections, would be very fast.

Comment: I can not use oracle SEQUENCEs. Because if there are 1000 companies, I have to create 1000 sequences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my colleagues has given good answer on it.

**Solution:**

1. Create an Oracle Sequence, which will be used for all Companies – this sequence will be used to generate the major version part of the sequence.
2. Create a running sequence (some random value with specific length) within Application code and use it as the minor version part of the sequence.

When persisting into the database, use the combination _ [e.g. 100_001] to uniquely identify a record. This way we don’t have to create n # of Oracle Sequences for n # of Companies. We can just create one, which will serve generating major version part of the sequence for all Companies. However, this will work if all Companies data is hosted in the same database. Just a thought.

This way we can avoid creating thousands of sequences and yet manage to have uniqueness for each company.

```
SQL> create sequence s1 start with 1000;

Sequence created.

SQL> create sequence s2 start with 6000;

Sequence created.

SQL> select to_char(s1.nextval)||'-'||to_char(s2.nextval) from dual;

TO_CHAR(S1.NEXTVAL)||'-'||TO_C
--------------------------------        
1000-6000

SQL> select to_char(s1.currval)||'-'||to_char(s2.nextval) from dual;

TO_CHAR(S1.CURRVAL)||'-'||TO_C
------------------------------        
1000-6001
```

For next company you may have 1001-6001  etc. So we manage everything with two sequences.

Answer (score 0):

keep LatestSequenceValue as is but instead of trying to get a next sequence value directly from it at each insert delegate this task to a singleton sequence generator. This sequence generator will take sequences from latestSequenceValue in batches, by that I mean it will increment the lastSequenceValue by 500 or something like that instead of incrementing the value by 1. Now the sequence generator singleton have a range of 500 values that if he distributes correctly will never cause duplicate ids. Now to distribute this value correctly the singleton needs to synchronize this operation someway. So now the singelton makes sure that a single application won't create duplicate ids and the sequence table will insure that all the sequence generators in all instances are not creating duplicate ids.

Comment: With this approach, ids will not be duplicated on different instances though. Lets take an example, there are 2 instances and by your singleton generator you generated 1-100 and 101-200 for instance 1 and 2 respectively. And suppose first two surveys served by first instance with sequences 1 and 2. And another two surveys served by second instance those will get sequences 101 and 102. Now in your database you have 4 surveys with sequence number 1,2,101,102. Instead surveys should get 1,2,3,4 sequence numbers. How to address this scenario?